# Filtro do mês e ano de uma data via combobox

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

Galera é o seguinte tenho uma tabela na minha base dados onde tenho o campo data_processo que está no formato date, sendo assim, todas as vezes que vou cadastar um processo no formulário de cadastro de processo seleciono uma data para cadastrar tal processo e os outros campo... Até aí tudo certo.
Porém estou criando um filtro via combobox, para buscar os processos das seguintes formas:

   Mês ou ano 
Dessa forma caso eu selecione apenas um dos dois campos, será exibido todos os processos do mês selecionado independente do ano, a mesma coisa acontece quando seleciono o ano ou seja, é exibido todos processos do ano selecionados idependente do mês.

   Mês e ano
Dessa forma caso eu selecione um mês e um ano será exibido somente os processos do mês e ano selecionado

Segue o código que já consegui fazer, dessa forma quando seleciono somente o mês é exibido todos os processos do mês selecionado independente do ano, porém quando seleciono somente o ano não é exibido nada, e quando seleciono as duas opções funciona de forma correta, ou seja é exibido os processos do mês e do ano selecionado. A busca só não acontece quando seleciono somente o ano. Alguém pode da uma força?

obs: estou usando php, mysql

```html
<form name="fmrpesquisa" id="frmpesquisa">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="">
          <select name="parametro_mes" id="parametro_mes" class="form-control">
            <option value="">MÊS</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="01">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
          </select>
        </div><br>

        <div class="col-sm-5" style="">
          <select name="parametro_ano" id="parametro_ano" class="form-control">
            <option value="">ANO</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
          </select>
        </div><br>

        <div class="col-sm-1" style="">
          <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
        </div>
      </div><br>
    </form>
```

```
<?php
$parametro_ano = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_ano");
$parametro_mes = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro_mes");

$sql = "SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,tb_processo.numero_processo,tb_processo.data_processo,tb_processo.assunto
            FROM 
            tb_processo
            WHERE(MONTH(data_processo) = '$parametro_mes' AND  YEAR(data_processo) = '$parametro_ano')";
$recebe = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: Cara você vai ter que gerar a sua consulta de maneira dinâmica. Sua variável $sql terá ir apenas até SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,tb_processo.numero_processo,tb_processo.data_processo,tb_processo.assunto FROM tb_processo . E aí você verifica se $parametro_ano é diferente de null se for você insere ela na query o mesmo para $parametro_mes e vai construindo a consulta de forma dinâmica. Pois quando você seleciona apenas o ano, para o banco você está pedindo um processo com o ano = 2019 com um mês nulo e aí ele não acha mesmo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT tb_processo.codigo_processo,
               tb_processo.numero_processo,
               tb_processo.data_processo,
               tb_processo.assunto
          FROM tb_processo
         WHERE 1 = 1";

if ( !empty($_REQUEST['parametro_ano']) )
   $sql .= " AND YEAR(data_processo) = ".$_REQUEST['parametro_ano'];

if ( !empty($_REQUEST['parametro_mes']) )
   $sql .= " AND MONTH(data_processo) = ".$_REQUEST['parametro_mes'];

echo $sql;

?>
<form name="fmrpesquisa" id="frmpesquisa">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="">
          <select name="parametro_mes" id="parametro_mes" class="form-control">
            <option value="">MÊS</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="01">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
          </select>
        </div><br>

        <div class="col-sm-5" style="">
          <select name="parametro_ano" id="parametro_ano" class="form-control">
            <option value="">ANO</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
          </select>
        </div><br>

        <div class="col-sm-1" style="">
          <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR">
        </div>
      </div><br>
    </form>
```